How do I fix a broken wicker basket hinge?
How can I fix this hinge? The wood part of the wicker basket where the hinge was originally screwed into has broken off so that section needs to be filled in it seems before I can screw in a new hinge. Any suggestions on what filler would be best? Or if in fact, there are better options?
Thanks

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We have a few prior Q&As on doing repairs that allow for screws to be reinserted that you should look at (and BTW you should have found with a search prior to asking). From the one photo it's not possible to get a full picture of what's going on here, but guessing a bit I think you should go into this knowing there's no guarantee any method can be directly applied here and afford a reliable repair. You can most definitely do something, just no way to be sure that there's enough material left, and that it is cohesive enough, to make a long-term repair feasible.
